# How to access 1 element in 2D dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++, and I've been trying to figure out how to access just 1 element in a 2D array that I've dynamically allocated like so:

```
char** array;
array = new char*[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    array[i] = new char [3];
}
```

I've been trying to access it like this:

```
cout<< array[0][0];
```

Whenever I try to do this, nothing prints out and the program segfaults.
How should I fix it so that it prints? 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It seems the above code shouldn't compile to start with: `new char*[3]` returns a `char**` but `*array` yields a `char*` (or my brain is fried for some reason...).

Comment: @DietmarKühl your brain isn't fried, it doesn't compile on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/yU11bj)

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake. I changed my code above.

Comment: Did you place any value in `array[0][0]`? If not, what did you expect to print?

Comment: I'm positive the array is filled. I want it to print the letter "a".

Comment: I'm not so positive. Post a [minimal and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not independent code lines.

Comment: Actually, I figured out my problem... I made a mistake dynamically allocating my array. Funny how I wasn't able to see that sooner. Sorry for all the trouble and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to create a 2D array you should take a look at this Stack Overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new). It has a nice image to explain how 2D memory is laid out and how to properly create the array. Remember, when you create dynamic memory using `new` you need to delete the memory manually with `delete[]`. The second response gives a code example of how to delete the 2D array. Once you have your array you can access it by `cout << array[x][y]`, where `x` and `y` are your row and column indices. I'd focus on properly creating the 2D array and understanding that first.